# Error on JPA many-to-many relationship between entity table and join table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I want a many-to-many relationship between an entity table and a join table. Invoices consist of a set of subscriptions. A subscription can be a part of multiple invoices (e.g. monthly subscription). Subscriptions consist of a user and a service. I am already using the subscriptions table as a join table for the many-to-many relationship between users and services (e.g. a user can subscribe to multiple services and a single service has multiple users). I have a table, "invoice_subscription," with IDs for both the invoice and subscription. Every table has its own ID. Below is the relevant snippet in the invoice object:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "invoice_subscription",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id")
)
public Set<Subscription> getSubscriptions() {
    return subscriptions;
}
```

I am using the following in the subscription object:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subscriptions")
public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
    return invoices;
}
```

For the above, I am receiving the error below:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKfe5yu82iapjynsdyfitclkri4:invoice_subscription [subscription_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (subscription [user_id,service_id])
```

When I switch to two "@JoinColumn" annotations with the IDs in the error, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.example.model.Subscription from com.example.model.Invoice has the wrong number of column. should be 1
```

I agree with this, but it seems to contradict the previous error. I've read documentation, guides, and other questions, but I have not found any useful information. I'm clearly missing something obvious.

Comment: What's the id in Subscription entity ?

Comment: All entities extend a `@MappedSuperclass` with a `private Long id;` The column in the invoice_subscription table is called "subscription_id." Using `referencedColumnName = "id"` in the `@JoinColumn` doesn't change anything.